# Cardinality of Cartesian Product where (a,b) are elements of A x B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having issues with a question regarding the cardinality of a cartesian product.

Question:
Let $A=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7\}$ and $B=\{0, 2, 4, −1, 12\}.$

How many elements are in $\{(a, b) ∈ A × B \; |  \; a < 7 \text{ and } b < 4\}$?

I want this to be $6 \cdot 3 = 18$. but that seems to be wrong.

Comment: It looks like $18$ to me. Are you sure you have transcribed the problem correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it's directly copied and pasted, I was not sure if I understood it right, but if you also say that 18 is the correct answer, I suspect the solution to be faulty.

Comment: What is the proposed  solution? Perhaps you can reverse engineer it to see what the solver was thinking.

Comment: Why does it seem wrong?

Comment: What does the "solution" say it is?

Comment: It's a multiple choice, where  I can choose between these answers:
0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may begin by omitting all $a \in A$ such that $a\ge 7$ and all $b \in B$ such that $b \ge 4$ because we know ordered pairs with said elements will not be included in the Cartesian product we're looking for. So, after omission, we have $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{0,2,-1\}$. Now, the cardinality of the Cartesian product between sets $A$ and $B$, denoted as $|A$ x $B|$, is given by $|A$ x $B|$ = $|A| \cdot |B| = 6 \cdot 3 = 18$. So you are correct! If your book says differently, then I highly suspect your book contains a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it seem wrong?

$\{(a,b)\in A\times B| a<7$ and $b< 4\}=$

$\{(a,b)| a\in \{k\in A|k < 7\}$ and $b\in \{j\in B|j < 4\}=$

$\{(a,b)| a \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $b \in \{-1,0,2\}\}=$

$\{0,1,2,3,4,5\} \times  \{-1,0,2\}$

And if $C, D$ are finite then $|C\times D| = |C|\cdot |D|$.

And as $|\{0,1,2,3,4\}|= 6$ and $|\{-1,0,2\}| = 3$ we have

$|\{0,1,2,3,4,5\} \times  \{-1,0,2\}= 6\cdot 3 = 18$

If you want we can even list them all:

$(0,-1),(0,0), (0,2),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,2), (2,-1),(2,0), (2,2),(3,-1),(3,0),(3,2),(4,-1),(4,0), (4,2),(5,-1),(5,0),(5,2)$.

.... I .... really have no idea why you think this seems wrong.  There are very few things in my life right now that feel as right as this feels.

Comment: Oh.... by "it seems to be wrong" did you mean "apparently the text gave a different solution"?  Or "this feels wrong"?

Comment: Yes, the OP thinks the book's answer is wrong. He says "seems to be", not just "seems".

Comment: If the books question is what the OP gave and the answer *isn't* what the OP gave, then the book answer *IS* wrong.  (Or we've *all* managed to make the same absurd counting mistake and none of us have caught it, but if there are $6$ elements of $A$ less than $7$ and $3$ elements of $B$ less than $4$ and if $6 \times 3$ does actually equal $18$, I'm not sure how any of us can be wrong...)

Answer (score -2):

If I've understood your question correctly, you'll begin by taking the appropriate subsets of A and B.

Since A = {0,1,2,3,4,5,7} and B = {0,2,4,−1,12}, and you're restricting your subsets to a < 7, and b < 4, this leaves the sets C = {0,1,2,3,4,5} and D = {0,2,-1}.

If you allow for repetition, which your question seems to assume, then there are 6 ways to select the first element, and 3 ways to select the second, implying a total of 18 ways to construct ordered pairs on the subsets.

Note that your textbook might be looking for un-ordered subsets of size 2, which is a different question.

Comment: This is the OPs answer, which the book says is wrong. The question asks explicitly about the cartesian product (so ordered pairs).

Comment: And I'm suggesting that perhaps OP misread the question, which would change the answer to the question, making the book right, and implying that OP just needs to re-read the question.